# JavaScript FireBase DisplayName SignUp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am working on my SignUp page for my app.
I can create an account and upload my profile picture to firebase but I can´t set my displayName.
Also I would like to create an username on signup. Is it possible?
My code:

```
createUser = async user => {
        let remoteUri = null;

        try {
            await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);

            let db = this.firestore.collection("users").doc(this.uid);

            db.set({
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                avatar: null
            });

            if (user.avatar) {
                remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(user.avatar, `avatars/${this.uid}`);

                db.set({ avatar: remoteUri }, { merge: true });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            alert("Error: ", error);
        }
    };
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I updated my security rules to

> allow read, write: if request.auth != null;